# How to hit a url from controller in MVC 5 and get the return data from that url to perform some task

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

How to hit a url from controller in MVC 5 and get the return data from that url to perform some task.

i mean suppose i am inside a controller and now need to call a url.
based on result from that url i have to perform some task in my controller.

Comment: do you want to make async call ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to another 3rd party JSON/RESTful type service?

Take a look at `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` and the third party library JSON.NET for parsing the results.

[Example on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

**Nuget packages:**

You will need to install the following Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
- Newtonsoft.Json

In the package manager console, you can do this by running: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`

*(the preceding command will install Newtonsoft.Json as a dependency)*

**Example code:**

The example code from the link above is using a Console app, but it would work fine from an ASP.NET service (see note below about "considerations"):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientSample
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static void ShowProduct(Product product)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {product.Name}\tPrice: " +
                $"{product.Price}\tCategory: {product.Category}");
        }

        static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "api/products", product);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // return URI of the created resource.
            return response.Headers.Location;
        }

        static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
        {
            Product product = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            }
            return product;
        }

        static async Task<Product> UpdateProductAsync(Product product)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(
                $"api/products/{product.Id}", product);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Deserialize the updated product from the response body.
            product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            return product;
        }

        static async Task<HttpStatusCode> DeleteProductAsync(string id)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(
                $"api/products/{id}");
            return response.StatusCode;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            // Update port # in the following line.
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64195/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {
                // Create a new product
                Product product = new Product
                {
                    Name = "Gizmo",
                    Price = 100,
                    Category = "Widgets"
                };

                var url = await CreateProductAsync(product);
                Console.WriteLine($"Created at {url}");

                // Get the product
                product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(product);

                // Update the product
                Console.WriteLine("Updating price...");
                product.Price = 80;
                await UpdateProductAsync(product);

                // Get the updated product
                product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(product);

                // Delete the product
                var statusCode = await DeleteProductAsync(product.Id);
                Console.WriteLine($"Deleted (HTTP Status = {(int)statusCode})");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Things to consider:**

Your web service is going to be relying on a third party web service now.  Is that what you really want?

If the other one is down, yours is down.  If the other one is slow, yours is slow.  Timeouts are something to think of - yours should be set to the same (or higher) than the other one probably.

Another option would be to have the data accumulated into your own database by a separate process, that way your web service doesn't get negatively affected by an outtage or slowness on the third party service.